# Stop the ongoing process(Thread) in Java on button click

Tags: java, multithreading, destroy

I have the following two buttons:

```
 jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

            Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    StreamingExperiment.streamingExperimentMain();
                }
            };
            t.setName("runThread");
            t.start();

        }
    });
```

and

```
 jButton3.setText("Cancel");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        }
    });
```

JButton3 is actually a cancel button which has to cancel the ongoing StreamingExperiment. How I am supposed to stop ongoing thread in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have the JButton's ActionListener call:

```
jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        StreamingExperiment.stop();
    }
});
```

You'll of course need to give StreamingExperiment this method whose contents will all depend on what StreamingExperiment does. If it has a loop, then perhaps `stop()` can change a boolean that you use to exit the loop.

By the way, it looks like StreamingExperiment has a static method, and you might want to fix this (unless it represents a variable, not a class in which case you should have its name start with a lower-case letter).

Answer (score 6):

You can't just stop any thread<sup>*</sup>. You can try [interrupting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) it:

```
t.interrupt();
```

But the thread has to be able to handle it. This brings a question, what does:

```
StreamingExperiment.streamingExperimentMain();
```

actually do? If it performs CPU intensive operations, the thread must periodically check [`isInterrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) flag and terminate if it happens to be set. If it waits on I/O or sleeps, chances are it will *just work* - see [`InterruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html).

<sup>Well, technically you [can](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29), but this method is deprecated for a reason.</sup>